# Python Selenium find_element_by не находит объект

Tags: python, selenium

Испытываю затруднения. 
После нажатия на button, на странице появляется окно. Окно всплывает поверх страницы. Не уверен, скорее всего это JS. В теле всплывающего окна находятся строки меню. Каждая строка имеет дропдаун (подменю). 
Необходимо методом find_element_by_xpath или find_element_by_css_selector найти объект и кликнуть по нему, далее, в открывшемся дропдауне, кликнуть на другой объект. 
Отваливается на последнем шаге скрипта. 
Что я делаю не так? assist me please? :(

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("my.webpage")

login = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
login.send_keys("user")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
password.send_keys("passwd")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/section/div/form/div[3]/button').click()

open_wizard = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/header/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/button')
open_wizard.click()
wizard_window = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html body.no-scroll div.ui-dialog.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-front.ui-draggable.ui-resizable')
```

Comment: Ну, нужно посмотреть что там всплывает... Мб там iframe?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста url